# table data to visual form before submission

Tags: jquery

I'm not sure the exact method this is called, so I'm leaving an image below for a better description for what I'm asking.

I'm looking for a jquery/php solution for this method.  I want to select a row in the table and be able to add the number of items to the visual form until the number reaches 0, or add them back to the table.  I would then like to take the visual form data and submit it to a php file.  Would anyone know of the proper jquery plugin to use for this?
[image: table data to visual form]

Comment: Are you looking for drag and drop? jQuery UI has the Draggable widget for that.

Comment: So far, the only thing I've found is jquery shopping cart plugins.  This is similar to what I need, but with more customizability.

eg On add to cart, check to make sure amount does not exceed available.